# SQL - Querying Two Tables and filtering out results

Tags: sql

Apologies for re-asking a common question. I have two tables (I didn't create these, just have to work with them)

1 - Cust
Contains basic customer data but not customer name. From here I have to
select customer number (cunr), pricelist (pr_lis) and price system (pr_sys)

2 - Cust_Name
Contains customer (and supplier) names and address details. Importantly it has two fields which marks an entry as a valid customer. So the key columns are cu_nr, cu_typ and cu_sys (typ and sys must equal 0)

So far, I have this query

```sql
select a.cunr,a.pr_lis,a.prl_sys,b.cu_nr 
from cust a 
  inner join cust_name b on a.cunr = b.cu_nr 
where (b.cu_typ = 0 and b.cu_sys = 0) 
order by 1,2,3
```

However when I run it, it was duplicating my results for every customer AND supplier instead of filtering out the suppliers (cu_typ = 0 means no suppliers)

Comment: Replicate issue here http://sqlfiddle.com/ and share url   i can see you had cu_typ = 0 in where clause

Comment: I've modified the original entry to make the cu_typ value make more sense

Comment: please replicate issue on sqlfiddle and sahre url

Comment: Could you provide sample data and expected result?